# How do i get the screen ID or the current screen

Tags: app-lab

I need to find the current id of the screen, but there doesn't seem to be a getscreen() command.

e.g.

```
onEvent(getScreen(),mousemove,function){
   ...
});
```

I tried to find a getProperty() from an element of the screen it was on but couldn't find anything